# Symfony 2 Doctrine Use find with between condition

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to find one record with between condition, and when I tried like this:

```
$paramHoraire = $em->getRepository('FrxintranetBundle:ParamPaye')->createQueryBuilder('a')
->where(':nbrDepots BETWEEN a.parampayeBornebas AND a.parampayeBornehaut')
->setParameter('nbrDepots', $nbrDep)
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

It returns an array and if I want to use a get method I have to do `$paramHoraire[0]->getParampayePourcentage()`
I want to know if they are a method like find to return just one line and not an array.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there can be more then just one match you will always get an array. It is also used this way in the docs of doctrine as you can see [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html). There are functions such as getSingleScalarResult() if you used COUNT() in your DQL.